# get the top N counts based on the value of another column

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with two columns that looks like this:

```
a 3
a 7
b 6
a 6
b 1
b 8
c 1
b 1
```

For each value in the first column, I'd like to find the top N counts from the second column. Using this example, I'd like to find the top 2 values in column 2 for each string in column 1. The desired output would be:

```
a 7
a 6
b 8
b 6
c 1
```

I was trying to do something like this with awk, but I am not that familiar with it. This gives the max, not top N:

```
awk '$2>max[$1]{max[$1]=$2; row[$1]=$0} END{for (i in row) print row[i]}'
```

Comment: What efforts did you make?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to use awk to store data in an array, but  I don't have much experience with awk and how to limit the number output to top N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, using `sort` + `awk` solution.

```
sort -k2 -s -nr Input_file | awk '++array[$1]<=2' | sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr
```

OR

```
sort -k2 -s -nr Input_file | sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr | awk '++array[$1]<=2'
```

***Logical brief explanation:*** First 2 sort commands are being used to sort data as per 1st and 2nd fields to get data in right order(as per OP's samples), then passing its output to `awk` to get only 1st 2 occurrences of each first field only as per ask.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2rn file | awk -v n=2 '(++cnt[$1])<=n'
a 7
a 6
b 8
b 6
c 1
```